# Proving a statistic is ancillary

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid observations from the pdf $f(x|\alpha)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x^\alpha}$, $x>0$, $\alpha>0$. Show that $\frac{\log X_1}{\log X_2}$ is an ancillary statistic.

I guess I need to show that the distribution of this statistic is independent of $\alpha$, i.e. it is the same as if $\alpha = 1$. However, this concept is a little bit confusing to me and I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: So did you actually try finding the distribution of $\log X_1/\log X_2$? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U\approx\mathsf{Exp}(1)$ then:$$P(U^{\frac1{\alpha}}>x)=P(U>x^{\alpha})=e^{-x^{\alpha}}$$ indicating that $U^{\frac1{\alpha}}$ has the distribution of $X_1,X_2$.

---

So $U_{i}:=X_{i}^{\alpha}$ are iid and have standard exponential distribution.

Then it follows easily that: $$\frac{\ln X_{1}}{\ln X_{2}}=\frac{\ln U_{1}}{\ln U_{2}}$$and distribution of RHS does not depend on $\alpha$ because the distribution of $U_1$ and $U_2$ does not depend on $\alpha$.

Comment: How does $U_i = X_i^\alpha$ follows from the same distribution?

Comment: The first displayed equation in the answer shows that the distribution functions of $U_i^{1/a}$ and $X_i$ are the same.  Hence the distributions of the $a$th powers of them are the same, too.

Comment: @kimchi lover But why does that mean that the variables are equal? I understand why they have the same distribution, but does that mean they are equal? I have examples like here in mind
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24938/can-two-random-variables-have-the-same-distribution-yet-be-almost-surely-differ

Comment: I would also add an example like this: $\Omega = \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}, P(\omega_1) = P(\omega_2) = \frac{1}{2}, X_1(\omega_1) = X_2(\omega_2) = 1, X_1(\omega_2) = X_2(\omega_1) = 0$.

Comment: @DeuzharNickens Which variables are claimed to be equal, by whom, and where?

Comment: @kimchi lover  "So $U_{i}:=X_{i}^{\alpha}$ are iid and have standard exponential distribution", right after the division line.

Comment: @DeuzharNickens Here drhab _defined_ $U_i$ to be $X_i^a$, that's why they are equal.  Since the $X_i$ are iid, the $U_i$ are too.  (The symbol $\defeq$ means "is defined to equal".)