# Proving a statistic is ancillary [link to an old question]

Tags: probability-distributions

It seemed pointless to write in the comments due to the question being old.
There is one question given 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3054960/proving-a-statistic-is-ancillary)
with an accepted answer that I can't understand.
It is implied there that from two random variables having the same distribution it follows that they are equal. Which is not true in general, [for example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24938/can-two-random-variables-have-the-same-distribution-yet-be-almost-surely-differ). What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see that implication in the cited answer.  Can you spell out more precisely how it goes?

Comment: @kimchi lover "..indicating that $U^{\frac1{\alpha}}$ has the distribution of $X_1,X_2$.

---

So $U_{i}:=X_{i}^{\alpha}$ are iid and have standard exponential distribution."

Comment: Explained by kimchi lover in the linked question. Thanks!